# Rails backend Role based Access control suggestion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, backbone.js

I need to implement role based access in the rails application we are building. The user and roles information are housed in a different db. authorized resources for a user are now  available by invoking the service. I need suggestion on how to implement this is in the backend. The UI is javascript heavy application.

The Roles information for user is also available as a service. my idea was to invoke that and define the rules in the backend. if you guys can point me in some direction that will great.

Thanks
Ramya

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I think I would add recordless models in app and incapsulate service calls in these models, so that it behaves as usual Rails model.

```
class User
  def self.find_by(*args)
    params_to_get_instance = #some service call with *args
    new(parmas_to_get_instance)
  end

  def role
    @role = #some service call ommited
  end
end
```

You can also take a look for modules (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel.html) which you can include in your model to get familiar ActiveRecord functionality. For example ActiveModel::Validations, ::Callbacks and so on.

Comment: Sure!! I was thinking all those lines too!! Thanks for your suggestion.